# Converting Python3 List(with str argument) to Bytes

Tags: python-3.x, sniffing

I am new to programming as well as python, i am trying use below code to sniff http packets.

I am getting below error, i know i can use  .encode() method instead try converting that list to bytes store it in a variable.

just wanted to understand my list **keywords** can this be converted to bytes.

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integ

My code

```
#!/bin/python3

import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers import http

def sniff(interface):
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packets)

def process_sniffed_packets(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):
        if packet.haslayer(scapy.Raw):
            load = (packet[scapy.Raw].load)
            keywords = ["usr", "username", "uname", "pwd", "pass", "password"]
            keyword_b = bytes(keywords)
            for eachword in keyword_b:
                if eachword in load:
                    print(load)
                        break
sniff(eth0)
```

Complete trace back

```
root@kali:~/python_course_zaid/Writing a Packet Sniffer# ./packet_sniffer.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./packet_sniffer.py", line 24, in <module>
    sniff("eth0")
  File "./packet_sniffer.py", line 7, in sniff
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packets)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 972, in sniff
    sniffer._run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 925, in _run
    session.on_packet_received(p)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scapy/sessions.py", line 47, in on_packet_received
    result = self.prn(pkt)
  File "./packet_sniffer.py", line 14, in process_sniffed_packets
    keyword_b = bytes(keywords)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

i know below code works

```
    keywords = ["usr", "username", "uname", "pwd", "pass", "password"]
    for eachword in keywords:
        if eachword.encode() in load:
            print(load)
            break
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the entire traceback, not just the error message.

Comment: What do you expect ``bytes(keywords)`` to do? The [``bytes`` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) takes either an integer, a list/iterable of integers or a bytes buffer. It does not take a list/iterable of strings, nor does it take individual strings. Do you want to know why you get the error, or what to do instead?

Comment: I just tried whether type conversion is possible with list iterable of strings, thanks for the confirmation so bytes type does not take list/iterable of strings

Comment: You could use a list comprehension to convert the list. Converting the list doesn't seem to have any advantage in your case, though.